# How do I get accurate search result in Lucene using Query syntax

Tags: lucene, sitecore

So far I have been testing the keywords that I inputted in Sitecore using the query syntax but the search result does not rank the page first.

For example if I put query syntax on the word book....(title:book)^1

I want the index page that is name book to appear first in the search result and not bookmark.

Also, every time I publish a new page in Sitecore the keywords for the word Book get push down to the last result or doesn't appear in the search page.

How do I get accurate result in Lucene for the search engine page?

Also I've been following http://www.lucenetutorial.com/lucene-query-syntax.html about how to increase search result but it doesn't work.

Can someone explain how the boost of the search term works.

Answer (score 2):

I recommend you leverage the [Advanced Database Crawler](http://svn.sitecore.net/AdvancedDatabaseCrawler/Branches/v2/) to get the best use of Lucene.NET with Sitecore. From that, there's a config file for the indexes with a section called `<dynamicFields ... >`. In that section, you can specify an individual Sitecore field and adjust the `boost` attribute. The default `boost` for every field is `1f` which is `1` floating point.

More reading:

- [Sitecore Searcher and Advanced Database Crawler](http://sitecoreblog.alexshyba.com/2010/11/sitecore-searcher-and-advanced-database.html)
- [Source code for the ADC](http://svn.sitecore.net/AdvancedDatabaseCrawler/Branches/v2/)

Comment: Hi Mark, is there a way to tuned the search result of the keywords by using Sitecore but without going through the backend coding. For example tuning the keywords in the meta data in Sitecore by using syntax terms. Also, every time I boost one attribute of the keyword the following keyword after that appears first in the search result which then drops the previous keyword to appear second in the search result. How do I prevent this from happening?

Comment: I'm not sure, that is getting very granular and custom. I only know about boosting an individual field as I mentioned.